# how to modify the value of a variable by its reference in a python function?

Tags: python

am trying to modify the value of some variable but I only success to read the value, not modify. In the following SWE, the point is to have three variable `imax,jmax,kmax` at the end of the loop for the following of the function. It is not to return them. This small example works like I wish if I am not in a function.

```
def subzoneStruct__(maxIndex):
  imax = maxIndex[0]
  jmax = maxIndex[1]
  kmax = maxIndex[2]
  print "before",locals()["imax"],imax
  for ind in ["imax","jmax","kmax"]:
    val=locals()[ind]
    print ind,val,
    if val > -1:
      val=max(1, val-1)
      print "in",val,
      locals()[ind]=val
      print locals()[ind],
    print "out",locals()[ind]
  print "after",locals()["imax"],imax
  print imax,jmax,kmax
  # Doing some stuff using imax,jmax,kmax
  # ...

subzoneStruct__((10,11,12))
print "should be (9,10,11)"
```

How Can I do to modify `imax,jmax,kmax` using the same loop (not necessarily using `locals`) ?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't do it that way, you're using the local variables as a poor substitute for a simple dictionary. It's almost always better to act as if `locals()` doesn't exist.

So then this becomes something like:

```
def subzoneStruct__(maxIndex):
    maxes = {"i": maxIndex[0], "j": maxIndex[1], "k": maxIndex[2]}

    for ind in ["i","j","k"]:
        val=maxes[ind]
        print ind,val,
        if val > -1:
            val=max(1, val-1)
            print "in",val,
            maxes[ind]=val
            print maxes[ind],
            print "out",maxes[ind]
     print "after", maxes["i"]
     return maxes["i"], maxes["j"], maxes["k"]
```

(probably indented the prints wrongs, but you get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I modify a bit my question in order to be more specific. I'd rather not use another variable (dictionnary) because I already need `imax,jmax,kmax` in the hidden part of my function.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to *do*, because this code isn't something I would write anyway; and remember that functions are supposed to be about 5 lines long, if there is more to it than this, your function is too long. Show your entire code here in order to get good answers, not just small parts. And finally, you really, really, don't need locals(), trust me.

Comment: I can't show the all function, it is about 200 lines long. But the thing is that I would have these three variables `imax,jmax,kmax` and correct them in the same way. I do agree that `locals` should be avoided, but is there another way to access to the value of an reference ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the most efficient way I found is to use comprehensive list

```
imax,jmax,kmax = [max(1, val-1) if val > -1 else val for val in maxIndex]
```

but my question stays valid on how to access and modify value from variable reference (using name or id or ...). So if you have an answer on that point, it could be nice to add it here.

Answer (score 0):

As RemcoGerlich said, you shouldn't be doing it that way. However a dictionary isn't required to store the three variables since a simple`list`is all that's needed. The following could be somewhat shortened, but it written to try to show what it's doing as clearly as possible and in a manner similar to the code in your question.

```
def subzoneStruct__(maxIndex):
    maxIndex = list(maxIndex)  # convert to mutable sequence
    imax, jmax, kmax = range(3)
    print 'before:', maxIndex[imax], maxIndex[jmax], maxIndex[kmax]
    for ind in imax, jmax, kmax:
        val = maxIndex[ind]
        if val > -1:
            val = max(1, val-1)
            maxIndex[ind] = val
    print 'after:', maxIndex[imax], maxIndex[jmax], maxIndex[kmax]
    # ...

subzoneStruct__((10,11,12))
print "should be (9,10,11)"
```